# how to call a specific javascript function from a set on page load event in vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a bunch of javascript (separated with different  tags in my aspx page.
Now i want to call a specific Javascript when a certain condition is valid on the page load.
The execution of this script would return few values which act as input for execution for rest of the vb.net code.
once the vb code execution is complete, i want the remaining javascript code to execute.

I have tried this way:

```
If CombinedMapPointsDropDownList.Items.Count = 0 Then
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "GetVals", "javascript:getCurrentPosition(pos);", True)
        End If
```

Upon executing this, all my javascript is getting executed.

Any ideas, please share. Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: All of your VB code executes first _on the server_ in order to produce the page that is sent to the browser. Once it gets to the browser the JS code executes. You can, however, have the JS code make a separate Ajax request back to the server at the appropriate time, allowing some more VB code to run - this is a separate request/response, but might achieve your end goal.

Comment: Initially, can we execute javascript based on conditions defined in code behind?

Comment: Hi nnnnn, thanks for the clear explanation. My question here is when the JS starts executing, can i restrict its execution only to a specific function and delay the rest to execute after the sever has finished execution of the rest of the vb code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the script which run after vb.net code execution from page load.And call the vb.net function as a Ajax call.Then on success method of the Ajax function you can put the remaining script.